# Is it possible to create a cross dissolve with two divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to create a *cross* dissolve transition where one element is dissolved as another is revealed?

I can post what I have but the difference is that one fades out while another fades in. I can only get them to fade in one after another. One fades out and then the other fades in.

Comment: you make both of them above each other and you simply fade out the top one and logically the bottom one will reveal

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Create two separate css animations (i guess this is the technique you are using) one for fade-in and the other one for fade-out.
Set the delay of fade-in animation to satisfy your needs, like so: `animation-delay: 3s;`.
The second animation will be delayed, effectively, you can set it to wait until the first one is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

In the example below I have a container element that will contain the content. The container element have `position:relative` to let it keep the position in the normal flow but also be an anchor for the children that will have `position:absolute` to let them contain the same place on screen (since the have position:absolute I also set the with and height).  I use [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) and [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to fade between the content.

The content by default have `opacity:0` to make it invisible. The rule `visible` will then change it to `opacity:1` and the transition will make it fade in and out over the specified time.

If the timing isn't what you want, you ca change it to any of `ease | ease-in | ease-out | ease-in-out | cubic-bezier(<number>, <number>, <number>, <number>)`. By defining the same property but with different values on `visible` and the default, you can have different values for fading in and out.

```js
"use strict";
const content = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

setInterval(()=>
  content.forEach( elem => elem.classList.toggle("visible")),
  3000
);
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative; /* bind coordonates to this element */
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  background:#ccc;
}
.content {
  position:absolute; /* let content overlap */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity:0; /* hide content */
  transition: opacity 2s;
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  background:#ccc;
  color:#000;
  overflow:auto;
}
.content.two {
  background:#88f;
  color:#fff;
}
.content.visible {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="content one visible">Hello!<br>This is content</div>
<div class="content two">This is another content</div>
</div>
```